# How to configure GWAN as a reverse proxy?

Tags: wordpress, reverse-proxy, g-wan

I saw some performance of GWAN and interested in testing it as a reverse proxy of static content in front of Apache with APC for optimizing PHP opcode, to run a Wordpress multisite.  I can get GWAN up and running but I have no idea how to configure it for reverse proxy, as there seems to be almost no information on it.  Anyone use GWAN as a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

It's still a not documented feature ... maybe in a next release ? @gil ?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's no easy way for you to do that. That will change with the next release.

We first hardcoded the reverse-proxy feature in G-WAN along with the load-balancer. Then, as we needed to personalize reverse-proxying, we implemented it as a `protocol handler` script.

`Protocol handler` scripts allow users to implement any protocol (like SMTP, LDAP, etc.) without haveing to deal with multi-threading nor socket events.

But finally, to reduce complexity for users, we might revert to the hard-coded implementation with `connection handlers` scripts to let people personalize the reverse proxy.

It's maturing under different use cases, hence the delay in publicly releasing this feature and a few others.

Rushing to implement features and interfaces is not always optimal, if the goal is to stay flexible and easy to use.